# Name or service not known using AWS SES in Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-3.6, airflow, amazon-ses

I am trying to send emails on failures in airflow and I get:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1475, in email_alert
    send_email(self.task.email, subject, html_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 60, in send_email
    mime_subtype=mime_subtype, mime_charset=mime_charset, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 106, in send_email_smtp
    send_MIME_email(smtp_mail_from, recipients, msg, dryrun)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 126, in send_MIME_email
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT) if SMTP_SSL else smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

`airflow.cfg` looks like:

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp

[smtp]
smtp_host = aws.mailing.company.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = XXXXXX
smtp_password = YYYYYY
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = name@aws.mailing.company.com
```

What does `Name or service not known` mean? Its that smtp_host is not correct or could be something else?

Comment: From the error it looks like airflow is not able to resolve the external domain names. Please also check if you can reach the smtp port from the host where you are running airflow. also check if this link helps. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=179624

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon i can't ping to that hostname from airflow. I will try to create my own SES domain it should fix it because all infra maintentance will be in my side.

Comment: Ok please let me know.